# Archive distribution problem for watch extension app

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, xcode10.1

We've been developing and testing a Watchkit Extension app (iOS 12.1 and WatchOS 5.1) for the past few months and successfully testing it on a simulator and local, connected devices (iPhoneX + Watch 4) using xCode 10.1.

This past week we built an archive for posting to App Store Connect. We got stuck in the Archive Organizer after archiving for release. The "Validate Content" button was disabled, the Version is blank, the Identifier is blank, and the Type is "Generic Xcode Archive". Unfortunately, all we can do is export the .app files from the Archive Organizer; we can't push the archive to App Store Connect.

We made sure the build scheme was set to Release and we archived to a Generic iOS and WatchOS device. We also set Skip Install for the three targets (iOS app, Watch app, Watch extension) to No as we assumed none of those are static libraries.  We even tried every permutation of Skip Install settings. We looked at the  issue in the following link and we have no Header steps in the Build Phases of any targets:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2215/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011221-CH1-PROJ

We have two frameworks we included in the project using carthage.  We thought maybe these were causing issues, but we rolled back to a branch before we added them and still have the same problem.

We made sure the build in the Scheme is set to a single target and cleared out the Derived Data folder.  Still no dice.

[image]

Comment: I figured it out after a lot of trial and error...  You must set the Skip install build setting for the iOS app to NO. You must set the Skip install build setting for the Watch app and Watchkit extension to YES. You must also set the Skip install build setting for your frameworks to YES.

Comment: Sorry, to hijack your post, but I am finding very few posts and users on SO who are dealing with watchOS companion app. I have a question, did you create 3 separate provisioning profiles i.e. one for each target i.e. one for iOS, one for watch app and one for watch extension? Also, what's the format of your bundle identifiers for each project?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. When I changed Skip install on the watch app and watch app extension to YES, it suddenly worked. No idea why.

Comment: I'll mention that XCode changed to Skip Install to 'NO' on me, possibly when I added a watch widget extension for a complication. Had to dig through commit logs to find unusual changes to the project.pbxproj file. It silently mangles bundle identifiers for watch apps too, you have to scrutinize the changeog any time the watch target is edited.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not 100% sure from your question, but are you trying to push an archive of the watch app to the App Store?

If so, that’s not how you submit the app. The Watch app is embedded in the “regular” iOS app, and to distribute it you need to archive and submit that app as usual.

If I’ve misunderstood, feel free to ignore this!